# Tracking offline ecommerce conversion in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have a Google Analytics account with active e-commerce tracking.

I'm trying to find an easy way how to import offline conversions to GA (f.e. visitor like something on a web but makes a call to order (we don't know the User-ID of a visitor)).

My vision was to create a simple two row table:

---

Date of call (conversion) | Value of conversion | SKU

Feb-01 | $100 | 12345ABC

Feb-01 | $1337 | 12345ABCD

Feb-02 | $250 | 12345ABCDE

---

Is this somehow possible? I'm trying to avoid hardcore API or measurement protocol programming (because I need to make it as simple as possible for further use).

The idea was to gather a list of all offline conversions in past week and then import it through Data Import. I just can't figure out how to set up the right data set in GA (and if that is even possible or if we need to use API or measurement protocol techniques)

EDIT: There are some articles that propose solution by generating coupon code (f.e. http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/universal-analytics-grab-offline-data-excel/ ). We can't offer coupons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data import does not allow to create hits from scratch, so your idea will not work.

One (relatively) easy idea would be to build an HTML form that allows your telephone operator to enter the products your visitor buys and that uses the standard e-commerce-tracking code to submit this to Google Analytics.

But if your backend system allows for modifications it would be better to connect your inventory management/fullfillment and GA via the measurement protocol (for one thing you would get consistent transaction ids between backend and GA).

Comment: Thanks for a comment. I was investigating that further and I'm more and more inclined to your solution. I think that HTML form is the easiest way.

Can I have one follow up question? Measurement protocol defines that I have to have cid value for each conversion (hit). Can I just generate one random cid and use that for all offline conversions? Would it work?

Comment: You can do that, but your reports will merge that into a single visitor with lots of transactions (I would probably generate a new cid for every call). You should perhaps add a custom dimension so you can segment offline transactions out, else this will affect your web tracking (metrics like conversion rate etc).